# Evaluate JavaScript AST directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, abstract-syntax-tree, evaluation

I maintain [doctest](https://github.com/davidchambers/doctest). The library uses an ECMAScript parser (Esprima) to extract comments from a JavaScript source file, then identifies “doctests” within these comments. For example:

```js
'use strict';

//  identity :: a -> a
//
//  > identity (42)
//  42
const identity = x => x;
```

The AST is then discarded, and JavaScript code is spliced into the original source text in place of the doctests. Imagine something like the following:

```js
'use strict';

//  identity :: a -> a
//
__doctest.enqueue (() => {
  assert.strictEqual (identity (42), 42);
});
const identity = x => x;
```

The modified source text is then saved to the file system. Finally, the newly created file is imported via `require`.

This approach works, but is circuitous:

```
SourceFile -> SourceText -> AST -> SourceText -> SourceFile -> SourceText -> AST -> Result
=(foo.js)=    (original) --------> (modified)    =(tmp.js)=    ====(require)====
```

Instead, I would like to do this:

```
SourceFile -> SourceText -> AST -> AST -> Result
```

I know how to perform the `AST -> AST` transformation. What I don't know is how to *evaluate* the modified AST. Surely it is not necessary to convert the AST to JavaScript source text only to have Node.js read the source text and recreate the AST!

Comment: Well The Esprima AST is a bunch of JavaScript objects (or actually some objects represented as C++ structures), while V8s AST is some C++ structures. The transformation AST -> AST is definetly not trivial, however this could work.

Comment: Good point, @JonasWilms. It now seems obvious that we're dealing with two very different representations of the same JavaScript program. Perhaps JavaScript source text really *is* the interchange format, enabling `Esprima -> SourceText -> V8`.

Comment: Well, the main question is: What is *necessary*? Can't we write the same AST transformations as C++ V8 modules? Can't we just write all our code in C++, getting rid of the whole parsing step? I think it's just way more convenient to write an esprima module than to write some C++ pointer logic. necessity is not necessarily a good motivation nowadays. move in measure.

Comment: I realized I can use [`vm.runInNewContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_contextobject_options) to obviate the need for a temporary file.